# Removing multiple elements from a vector c++

Tags: c++, vector

Here is some code which checks if 2 units are killed after they attack each other, I pass in the position in the vector however when I remove one the vector is changed in size and therefore the 2nd unit is out of range. How can I remove both simultaneously?

```
if ((MyHealth <= 0) && (EnemyHealth <= 0))
{
    PlayerUnits.erase(PlayerUnits.begin() + MyUnit, PlayerUnits.begin() + EnemyUnit);
}
else if (MyHealth <= 0)
{
    PlayerUnits.erase(PlayerUnits.begin() + MyUnit);
}
else if (EnemyHealth <= 0)
{
    PlayerUnits.erase(PlayerUnits.begin() + EnemyUnit);
}
```

Comment: Erase the bigger index first

Comment: @DieterLücking, that is the answer.  You should make it so :)

Comment: If you don't have to preserve the order of the elements in vector, it should be faster to swap element(s) you want to remove with last element(s) of the vector, and trim the size of the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First point: In your first block, the call `erase(x, y)` does something different than you expect - it erases a whole *range* of elements starting at index x until just before index y. For example, if we have the vector [a,b,c,d,e,f,g], then erase(2,5) will erase indexes 2,3,4, so we end up with [a,b,f,g]. I'm guessing you want to erase just two elements, not an entire range.

Second point: As Dieter Lücking pointed out, simply erase the higher index element first, like this:

```
if (MyUnit > EnemyUnit) {
    PlayerUnits.erase(PlayerUnits.begin() + MyUnit);
    PlayerUnits.erase(PlayerUnits.begin() + EnemyUnit);
} else {
    PlayerUnits.erase(PlayerUnits.begin() + EnemyUnit);
    PlayerUnits.erase(PlayerUnits.begin() + MyUnit);
}
```

Comment: I did not vote on your answer at all. Please do not make this kind of accusation at me.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of coding the removal logic yourself, it would be better managed using `std::remove_if` from `algorithm`. Depending on whether you have compiler supporting C++11 or not, the Predicate can either be a lambda or a named function.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to handle this would be to add an "isDead" condition to your "unit" class:

```
void Unit::Update()
{
    //other stuff
    if(this->m_health <= 0) this->m_isDead = true;
}
```

then in the main loop:

```
void Game::Update()
{
   size_t size = PlayerUnits.size();

   //iterate backwards, so there is no skipping
   for(int i = size-1; i>= 0; i--)
   {
       PlayerUnits[i]->Update();
       if(PlayerUnits[i]->isDead()) PlayerUnits.erase(PlayerUnits.begin() + i);
   }
}
```

This is at least how I personally do it.